# Long block of text in Jade textarea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, pug

I'm using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) in my latest node.js app. I'd like to have a long block of text in a textarea by default.

If I do something like this:

```
textarea(id="theTextarea")
```

it renders just fine:

```
<textarea id="theTextarea"></textarea>
```

However, if I do something like so:

```
textarea(id="theTextarea")
  Hello world.
```

I get this:

```
<textarea id="theTextarea">
  <hello>world</hello>
</textarea>
```

But I'd like it to be like so:

```
<textarea id="theTextarea">
  hello, world
</textarea>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is shown very clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
textarea(id="theTextarea")
  | Hello 
  | world.
  | Hello
  | moon.
  | Hello
  | sun.
```

Answer (score 11):

The | worked great for me. In my case though, I needed to get the value from a js variable (passed via render local variables). This is what I ended up with:

```
textarea#resp( name="resp", rows="6", cols="66" )
  | #{respStr}
```

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this, if you don't want a lot of pipes "clogging up" your markup (notice the dot character after the closing parens):

```
textarea(id="theTextarea").
  Hello
  world.
  Hello
  moon.
  Hello
  sun.
```

Read through the [Tag Text](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#tag-text) section in the Jade docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I see this might be too late but hope it can help someone else,
when working with textarea and want to output dynamic data, this worked for me

```
textarea.form-control#pdt_desc(name="pdt_desc", cols="10", rows="2")= product.pdt_desc
```

Reference: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2018