# Iterate over object and display results in textarea without html tags

Tags: pug

I have an object that I've returned from my route controller and I know how to how iterate and display it but only with an html tag prepended on the object.

```
textarea(rows="5" id="words" name="words")
    for value in object
        p= value.word
```

I've also tried following the solution posted at this question which is similar [Long block of text in Jade textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659775/long-block-of-text-in-jade-textarea) but it doesn't involve iterating and pug doesn't recognize it as part of the loop and it just directly prints value.word in the textarea.

```
textarea(rows="5" id="words" name="words")
    for value in object
        | value.word
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your object is a string array. You can combine these values on a separate variable using new line between them. Then you can use this variable for the textarea as follows

```
- var result = ""
for value in object
    - result = (result + value + "\n" )

textarea(rows="5" id="words" name="words")=result
```